# add fields in meta data using django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The response from my application is as below, but I want to add another field next to `previous` in metadata, how to add `IP` to metadata

```
{
 "count": 100,
 "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/?page=2",
 "previous": null,
 "results": [
         {
          "first_name": "john",
          "last_name": "a",
          "mail": "johnabi@mail.com"
         }
  ]
}
```

I want my results to be:

```
    {
     "count": 100,
     "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/?page=2",
     "previous": null,
     "ip-adress":0.0.0(something)
     "results": [
             {
}
```

Comment: what did you mean `add` metadata `without adding` can you show example?

Comment: I have made some changes in the question @Bear Brown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by docs [custom-pagination-styles](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles) you can try

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def ip_data(self):
        # YOU CUSTOM CODE HERE
        return '0.0.0.0'

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):

        return Response({
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data,
            'ip-adress': self.ip_data()
            # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        })
```

and in the settings update data for paginator

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'my_project.core.pagination.CustomPagination',
     #                      ^^^ CHANGE PATH TO YOUR PAGINATOR CLASS ^^^
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

Comment: Thank you,and we can just include our pagination into views as pagination_class